# How to Pass JavaMail Message Object to another activity in android

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

I am reading emails using JavaMail api in android. Can anyone please tell how can I pass the Javax.mail.Message object via Intent to another activity? Is this possible?

Thank you.

Regards,

Comment: you can pass via serialization or parcable objects.

Comment: use `Parcelable`, its faster than `serialization`

Answer (score 0):

i think you should make your object Serializable then pass the object within intent using

```
i.putExtra("class name", object); // to pass the object  

super.getIntent..getSerializableExtra("class name") // retrieve the object in the second activity
```